# Hello World in Java won't compile

Tags: java, eclipse, virtual-machine

In eclipse, I suddenly get the following error:
`<terminated> Adding more memory. [Java Application] /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`

With the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I've tried googling it, and I have no idea why this is occurring... I've tried closing and reopening eclipse, and rebooting. I was happily coding an Android project (which was compiling a few minutes ago) when this started happening.

FYI, the code I am trying to compile is:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

It works, however in the terminal (after silly late night correction)

```
Jono@Lappy:/Users/Jono/Workspace/HelloWorld/src$ ls
HelloWorld.java

Jono@Lappy:/Users/Jono/Workspace/HelloWorld/src$ javac HelloWorld.java 

Jono@Lappy:/Users/Jono/Workspace/HelloWorld/src$ ls
HelloWorld.class    HelloWorld.java

Jono@Lappy:/Users/Jono/Workspace/HelloWorld/src$ java HelloWorld
Hello World
```

I am running a Macbook Pro with OSX 10.7.5, completely up to date.

Comment: does it happen everytime you open the eclipse?

Comment: Only after compiling, when trying to run. Same thing happens when compiling from terminal (see edits) - but it started while using Eclipse.

Comment: Try this: java HelloWorld

Comment: Sorry it's late :) Same issue still exists in eclipse though.

Comment: Seeing as the topic has been closed, I can't provide an accepted answer. The issue was the JVM was somehow removed from the classpath of the run/debug configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Omit the .class

```
java HelloWorld
```

Comment: Sorry it's late :) Same issue still exists in eclipse though.